# Parse number to pull out mean of multiple Numbers from a column

Tags: r, parsing, tidyverse, tidyr

So I have a dataframe like below & what I have done is create a new column income by simply doing `income=parse_number(family_income)`, but what I want is to have mean of both numerical values then display as income.

**Expected output for 1st entry would be (75000+99999)/2 = 87499.5**

I want to use modern R functions like parse_number or something better to do this efficiently.

```
library(tidyr)
family_income        income
   <chr>                 <dbl>
 1 $75,000 to $99,999    75000
 2 $50,000 to $74,999    50000
 3 $0 to $9,999              0
 4 $200,000 and up      200000
 5 $100,000 to $124,999 100000
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way would be to remove commas and then extract numbers and take `mean`

```
library(stringr)
df$income <- purrr::map_dbl(str_extract_all(str_replace_all(df$family_income,
           ",", ""), "\\d+"), ~mean(as.numeric(.x)))

df
#         family_income   income
#1   $75,000 to $99,999  87499.5
#2   $50,000 to $74,999  62499.5
#3         $0 to $9,999   4999.5
#4      $200,000 and up 200000.0
#5 $100,000 to $124,999 112499.5
```

---

Using base R, we can use `regmatches` and `gregexpr`

```
temp <- gsub(",", "", df$family_income)
sapply(regmatches(temp, gregexpr("\\d+", temp)), function(x) mean(as.numeric(x)))
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(family_income = structure(c(5L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 2L
), .Label = c("$0 to $9,999", "$100,000 to $124,999", "$200,000 and up", 
"$50,000 to $74,999", "$75,000 to $99,999"), class = "factor")), 
row.names = c(NA,-5L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Thanks Ronak, Could parse_number be somehow used to extract both numbers from first column (even if into two columns) then I can take mean of that. I just really have a tough time spinning my head around regular expressions

Comment: @VaibhavSingh I think `parse_number` can extract only one (first) number from the string and not multiple numbers.

Comment: A faster base R approach would be something like `vapply(strsplit(gsub("(\\$|,| and up)", "", df$family_income), " to ", TRUE), function(x) mean(as.numeric(x)), numeric(1L))`.

Answer (score 2):

Base R solution not as eloquent as @Ronak Shah:

```
df$income <- do.call("rbind",
                    lapply(strsplit(gsub("[[:alpha:]]|\\s+", "",
                       gsub(" to ", ":",
                            gsub("[[:punct:]]", "", df$family_income))), ":"),
       function(x){mean(as.numeric(x))}))
```

Comment: I don't really see anything wrong with this answer (+1). I'd probably `unlist` rather than using `do.call(rbind, ...)` but since we already know that we're going to want to simplify, using `sapply` or `vapply` makes more sense rather than `unlist(lapply(...))`.

Comment: Thank you, yes vapply/sapply are better then unlisting the returned list, and the nested gsubs don't feel that nice. Great solution and cheers for the comment and upvote - returned the favour.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative base R approach could be:

```
vapply(strsplit(gsub("(\\$|,| and up)", "", df$family_income), " to ", TRUE), 
  function(x) mean(as.integer(x)), numeric(1L))
```

This is as fast as if not slightly faster than Ronak Shah's stringr + purrr approach, and faster than the existing base R approaches shared so far.

If further efficiency is required, you can consider writing a function like the following:

```
library(data.table)
parse_income <- function(instring) {
  as.data.table(instring)[
    , temp := gsub("(\\$|,| and up)", "", instring)][
      , c("v1", "v2") := tstrsplit(temp, " to ", fixed = TRUE, type.convert = TRUE)][
        , rowMeans(.SD, na.rm = TRUE), .SDcols = c("v1", "v2")]
}
```

It can then be used like this:

```
parse_income(df$family_income)
## [1]  87499.5  62499.5   4999.5 200000.0 112499.5
```

---

Here's a quick benchmark starting with the sample data from Ronak Shah's answer. The data to be parsed has been expanded to 10,000 values.

```
inc <- rep(df$family_income, 1e4/nrow(df)) # Adjust to get a sense of how each approach scales

base_am <- function(instring) {
  vapply(strsplit(gsub("(\\$|,| and up)", "", instring), " to ", TRUE), 
         function(x) mean(as.integer(x)), numeric(1L))
}

base_rs <- function(instring) {
  temp <- gsub(",", "", instring)
  sapply(regmatches(temp, gregexpr("\\d+", temp)), function(x) mean(as.numeric(x)))
}

base_hf <- function(instring) {
  do.call("rbind",
          lapply(strsplit(gsub("[[:alpha:]]|\\s+", "",
                               gsub(" to ", ":",
                                    gsub("[[:punct:]]", "", instring))), ":"),
                 function(x){mean(as.numeric(x))}))
}

stringi_rs <- function(instring) {
  purrr::map_dbl(str_extract_all(str_replace_all(instring, ",", ""), "\\d+"), ~mean(as.numeric(.x)))
}

bench::mark(base_am(inc), base_rs(inc), base_hf(inc), stringi_rs(inc), parse_income(inc), check = FALSE)
## # A tibble: 5 x 13
##   expression             min   median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec` n_itr  n_gc total_time result            memory          time   gc          
##   <bch:expr>        <bch:tm> <bch:tm>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl> <int> <dbl>   <bch:tm> <list>            <list>          <list> <list>      
## 1 base_am(inc)          48ms   49.5ms     20.1   312.69KB     2.01    10     1      498ms <dbl [10,000]>    <df[,3] [4 × 3… <bch:… <tibble [11…
## 2 base_rs(inc)        99.4ms  127.6ms      8.38   80.04MB     2.79     3     1      358ms <dbl [10,000]>    <df[,3] [20,01… <bch:… <tibble [4 …
## 3 base_hf(inc)        67.1ms   68.4ms     14.4    547.2KB     2.06     7     1      485ms <dbl[,1] [10,000… <df[,3] [7 × 3… <bch:… <tibble [8 …
## 4 stringi_rs(inc)     50.3ms   51.8ms     19.1   324.16KB     2.12     9     1      472ms <dbl [10,000]>    <df[,3] [38 × … <bch:… <tibble [10…
## 5 parse_income(inc)   14.8ms     15ms     66.1     1.01MB     0       34     0      514ms <dbl [10,000]>    <df[,3] [30 × … <bch:… <tibble [34…
```